# Dovecot – Can send, not receive mail (visable in mail queue) Where is email?

Tags: centos, email, dovecot, exim

**Mail queue administration say’s:**

```
Received from myemail@adres.com H=mail-wm0-f44.google.com [74.125.82.44] P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no S=3663 DKIM=gmail.com id=CALSm3d9r2Qd9JcO-AFg+inZmKheuq0w9PzErUv98tjh0bg5KmQ@mail.gmail.com T="Re: test mail "

myemail@adres.com R=virtual_user T=dovecot_lmtp_udp defer (-1): Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dovecot/lmtp for dovecot_lmtp_udp transport: No such file or directory
```

**/var/log/exim/mainlog**

```
1fT4jr-0005si-Ro  for myemail@adres.com

cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1fT4jr-0005si-Ro

1fT4jr-0005si-Ro == myemail@adres.com R=virtual_user T=dovecot_lmtp_udp defer (-1): Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dovecot/lmtp for dovecot_lmtp_udp transport: No such file or directory
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf**

```
## Dovecot 2.0 configuration file

#IPv4
#listen = *

#IPv4 and IPv6:
listen = *, ::

protocols = imap pop3 lmtp

auth_username_chars = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.-_@&
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
login_greeting = Dovecot DA ready.
mail_access_groups = mail
default_login_user = dovecot
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

default_process_limit=512
default_client_limit=2048

passdb {
  driver = shadow
}
passdb {
  args = username_format=%n /etc/virtual/%d/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  process_min_avail = 16
  user = dovecot
}
service pop3-login {
  process_min_avail = 16
  user = dovecot
}

ssl_cert = /etc/exim.cert
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP
ssl_key = /etc/exim.key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = username_format=%n /etc/virtual/%d/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
verbose_proctitle = yes
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
  pop3_logout_format = top=%t/%p, retr=%r/%b, del=%d/%m, size=%s, bytes=%i/%o
}

mail_max_userip_connections = 15
remote 127.0.0.1 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 40
}

# LMTP socket for local delivery from exim
service lmtp {
  executable = lmtp -L
  process_min_avail = 16
  unix_listener lmtp-client {
    user = mail
    group = mail
    mode = 0660
  }
}

protocol lmtp {
  log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lmtp-errors.log
  info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lmtp.log
  postmaster_address = postmaster@HOSTNAME
}
```

I have recent update Centos, Directadmin & database, before that i never had any problems.

Comment: Can you show exim's and dovecot's configs?

Comment: /var/run/dovecot/lmtp don't exists ! Do you activate lmtp in dovecot ?

Comment: file etc/exim.conf was to big to post, is there a specific chapter you looking for? And I also didn't acitvate anything as it works before the update, how can i activate so I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was dovecot

I have found the solution that worked for me.

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
./build exim
./build exim_conf
mv /etc/dovecot /etc/dovecot~moved 
./build dovecot
./build dovecot_conf
```